# Can someone explain how contribute_to_class works?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on an extending a current project and came cross this line of code:

```
MyGenericRelation().contribute_to_class(model, 'field_name')
```

The result of this code is a field with 'field_name' added to the 'model' and from what I gather, the objects inside the field are a list of type X (part of MyGenericRelation).

I wanted to understand how this `contribute_to_class` method works. Why do I get a list of X objects attached to 'field_name' and does it have to be generic relations?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do and why you think you need to modify this code? What are you not able to achieve with normal generic relations?

Answer (score 56):

Basically, for objects that have a `contribute_to_class` method, when adding them to a Model class, we call `contribute_to_class` instead of `setattr`: this allows objects to do additional book-keeping and/or modification of the class as they are added. Alex Gaynor has a good explanation here: http://lazypython.blogspot.com/2008/11/django-models-digging-little-deeper.html