# Following users like twitter in Django, how would you do it?

Tags: python, django, database-design, twitter, django-models

I am playing with relationships in Django/python and I am wondering how you guys would create a relationship between a User and his followers and a Follower to the users he follows.

Would love to read your opinion...

Comment: Unless you've got a specific programming-related question, this is better suited as a post in a forum.

Comment: @patrickn most probably yes but it could also be seen as a question. Since I don't have a clue were to start I ask about it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, you should understand how to [store additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users). It requires another model that has a relation to one user, the "profile" model.

Then, you could use an M2M field, assuming you'd use [django-annoying](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying), you could define your user profile model as such:

```
from django.db import models

from annoying.fields import AutoOneToOneField

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField('auth.user')
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('UserProfile', related_name='followed_by')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

And use it as such:

```
In [1]: tim, c = User.objects.get_or_create(username='tim')

In [2]: chris, c = User.objects.get_or_create(username='chris')

In [3]: tim.userprofile.follows.add(chris.userprofile) # chris follows tim

In [4]: tim.userprofile.follows.all() # list of userprofiles of users that tim follows
Out[4]: [<UserProfile: chris>]

In [5]: chris.userprofile.followed_by.all() # list of userprofiles of users that follow chris
Out[5]: [<UserProfile: tim>]
```

Also, note that you could check / reuse apps like [django-subscription](https://github.com/subsume/django-subscription), [django-actstream](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream), [django-social](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-social) (harder to use probably)...

You might want to take a look at the django packages for [notifications](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/notification/) and [activities](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/activities/) as they all require some follow/subscription database design.

Comment: I have Created a UserProfile. I think a manytomanyfield is the way i should go. But in this line chris.userprofile.followed_by.all() <-- did you define a followed_by function?

Comment: Actually, followed_by is the **related_name** of the UserProfile.follows field. By default, it would be userprofile_set which is not really informative.

Comment: And what about feeds? Like fb's news feed?

Comment: For this to work for me, I also had to set symmetrical=False as detailed in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42040848/1991735

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it:

```
class Tweeter(models.Model):  
    user = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, through='Relationship')

class Relationship(models.Model):  
    who = models.ForeignKey(Tweeter, related_name="who")
    whom = models.ForeignKey(Tweeter, related_name="whom")
```

In the shell,

> In [1]: t = Tweeter()
>
> In [2]: t.save()
>
> In [3]: f = Tweeter()
>
> In [4]: f.save()
>
> In [5]: r=Relationship()
>
> In [6]: r.who=t
>
> In [7]: r.whom=f
>
> In [8]: r.save()
>
> In [18]: Relationship.objects.all()[0].who.id
>   Out[18]: 1L
>
> In [19]: Relationship.objects.all()[0].whom.id
>   Out[19]: 2L

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Makes more sense to use ManyToManyField, as the commenter suggests. Users can have 0-x User followers, and Users can follow 0-x Users.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

Without going into code, not much more to be said.

Comment: An FK is useful for a 0:1 relation. In the case you're attempting to describe, a user can have 0:n followers and he can follow 0:n users. Thus, the relation would be n:m.

Comment: I stand corrected, forgot about the 0 followed users/0 followers case.

Comment: Rather, the 'many followed' and 'many followers', as an FK only allows to relate to one user.

Comment: Also you cannot add an M2M between user and user unless using the unsupported [contribute to class method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357528/explanation-of-contribute-to-class).