# Django Model ManyToMany Reverse Filter

Tags: python, django, filter, manytomanyfield

Here's excerpts from (something analogous to) my models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self',
    through='Relationship',
    symmetrical=False,
    related_name='related_to',
  )
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Relationship(models.Model):
  from_person = models.ForeignKey(Person,
    related_name='from_people',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
  )
  to_person = models.ForeignKey(Person,
    related_name='to_people',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
  )
  status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  def __str__(self):
    return "{} is {} {}".format(
      self.from_person.name, self.status, self.to_person.name)
```

Here's the contents of my database:

```
>>> Person.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Person: A>, <Person: B>, <Person: C>]>
>>> Relationship.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Relationship: B is Following C>]>
```

If I want to see who a given person is following, I can build a new method into the Person class:

```
def get_following(self):
  return self.relationships.filter(
    to_people__status='Following',
    to_people__from_person=self)
```

This works:

```
>>> p2.get_following()
<QuerySet [<Person: C>]>
```

I want to do the REVERSE of this.  Instead of asking "Who does this person follow?", I want to ask "Who follows this person?".  I can do that like this (although it returns Relationship objects, not Person objects):

```
>>> Relationship.objects.filter(to_person=p3, status='Following')
<QuerySet [<Relationship: B is Following to C>]>
```

My attempt is this (which returns an empty QuerySet):

```
def get_following(self):
  return self.relationships.filter(
    from_people__status='Following',
    from_people__to_person=self)
```

Your help is appreciated!

EDIT:
Here's the ANSWER I chose:

```
def get_followers(self):
  return self.related_to.filter(from_people__status='Following')
```

Comment: Do you want from people, or to people, or all people?

Comment: A QuerySet of all People that follow a given person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the ANSWER I chose:

```
def get_followers(self):
  return self.related_to.filter(from_people__status='Following')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else needs another way of implementing "Followers" exactly like you described, but with a different modelling scheme:

```py
# project/account/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from model_utils import Choices

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class Meta:
        # ...

    username = models.CharField(...)
    email = models.EmailField(...)
    # ...

    ### Custom app-specific relationships (database scheme) ###

    # symmetrical=False is needed for this reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42040848/3433137
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

```py
# project/account/forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from .models import User

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...

    # new:
    following = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name='Following',
            is_stacked=False
        )
    )
    # new:
    followers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name='Followers',
            is_stacked=False
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        # add 'following' and 'followers' to the fields:
        fields = ('email', 'password', ..., 'following', 'followers')

    # also needed to initialize properly:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Filter out the self user in the lists and initialize followers list:
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['following'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                queryset=User.objects.all().exclude(pk=self.instance.pk),
                required=False,
                widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
                    verbose_name='Following',
                    is_stacked=False
                )
            )
            self.fields['followers'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                queryset=User.objects.all().exclude(pk=self.instance.pk),
                required=False,
                widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
                    verbose_name='Followers',
                    is_stacked=False
                )
            )
            self.fields['followers'].initial = self.instance.followers.all()
```

```py
# project/account/admin.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import User
from .forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm


class Admin(BaseUserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = UserChangeForm
    model = get_user_model()

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'is_admin']
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('username',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff')}),
        # new:
        ('Following / Followers', {'fields': ('following', 'followers')}),
    )
    # other fields
    # ...

    # new:
    filter_horizontal = ('following', 'followers')

admin.site.register(User, Admin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

If you then start the server and go to localhost:8000/admin/
and navigate to a user's detail-page, you should see something like this on your screen:

[image]

I did not add counters so you are able to see the amount of followers at once in the list_view.

**Note** that the second FormField with the followers is read-only in the admin panel. A user cannot choose other users to follow him.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) document.  Otherwise here are some other methods...

`self.relationships.from_people.objects.all()` would return all objects with of with the related name `from_people`.

I would, however, slightly change some code such that the use would be `self.relationships.from_people.objects.filter(status='Following')`

Another way to do it (though not the most efficient) is to pass in the person model, and pass in the relationships model using the person.pk as a filter.

```
def get_following(self, pk):
    person = Person.objects.get(pk=pk)
    relationships = Relationship.objects.filter(to_person=person.id)
    return relationships
```

Comment: For your first two code blocks, I'm told: 'AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'objects'. In the end, I used the 'related_name" to work backward.

Answer (score 0):

You got a QuerySet like this: `<QuerySet [<Relationship: B is Following C>]>`. Think that one day (I guess that it is the propose of that) 'person' has a lot of followers and it probably might return so many followers, like this: `<QuerySet [<Relationship: B is Following C>, <Relationship: A is Following C>]>`.
So, I would use values_list() [1]:

```
Relationship.objects.filter(to_person=p3, status='Following').values_list('from_person__name', flat=True)
```

Returns: `<QuerySet [A, B, ...]>`

If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat parameter. If True, this will mean the returned results are single values, rather than one-tuples.

or create a method:

```
def get_followers(self):
    follower_of_person = []
    for value in relation_of_person:
        follower_of_p3.append(value.from_person.name)
    return follower_of_person
```

Returns: `[A, B, ...]`

values_list still is better, because you are working directly on the database.

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list
(Here have a good example of ManyToMany).

Comment: If you do not want the name, remove `name` and you will get something like `<QuerySet [<Person: A>, <Person: B>, ...]>`

Comment: I'm okay remaining with a QuerySet.  This is just a toy example, so there will be lots of relationships.  Have a look at the answer I added that uses the 'related_name' to work backward.